# How to send solana using using python?

Tags: transactions, solana.py

a bit new to the Solana development, I am trying to create a program that can send a certain amount of Solana from my wallet to a particular address. I found some code but am not really understanding how it works. I am also having trouble understanding how I can switch from devnet to mainnet. I tried switching to mainnet beta but it wasn't really working. Any help would be helpful.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python you can send SOL as follows:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer

LAMPORT_PER_SOL = 1000000000

client: Client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")

sender = Keypair.generate()
receiver = Keypair.generate()

airdrop = client.request_airdrop(sender.public_key, 1 * LAMPORT_PER_SOL)
airdrop_signature = airdrop["result"]
client.confirm_transaction(airdrop_signature)

transaction = Transaction().add(transfer(TransferParams(
    from_pubkey=sender.public_key,
    to_pubkey=receiver.public_key,
    lamports=1_000_000)
))

client.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
```

The above code sends SOL from the `sender` to `receiver`

Comment: Okay this helps a bit, but, how can I transition from devnet to mainnet?

Comment: @TanayUpreti Just update the `Client` url to point to a mainnet RPC

Comment: please ask new questions in new posts rather than in the comments